# How to have a reference frame for markerless inside out tracking in VR, to achieve absolute positional tracking and prevent drift

Tags: unity-game-engine, positioning, tracking, absolute, virtual-reality

We have the new Vive Focus headset, which has markerless inside out tracking. By default these headsets can only do relative tracking from their initial position. But this isn't totally accurate, you get some drift, and the position in the virtual world and the real world go out of sync. For the y position, this can mean ending up at the wrong height in the virtual world as well. Also, you don't know the user's absolute position, which you would need for a mulitplayer game for instance, so your players don't run into each other.

Now the ZED camera from Stereolabs has an option to use a reference frame (which I assume is a pointmap), which it will then use to do absolute positional tracking by calculating your position relative to the reference frame, instead of to the last frame (which I assume normal markerless inside out tracking does). Of course the ZED code is in a dll, so my question is, how difficult is it to code this system using a reference frame for the Vive Focus or another markerless inside out tracked headset. Preferably in C#, preferably using the Unity plugin, but any example would help.

And what I'm wondering about this reference frame system is would one reference frame be enough? The ZED documentation says you need to look at approximately the same scene as you were when you first made the reference frame. This makes sense, otherwise how would the system find its reference. But doesn't that mean you would need more references, for the other sides of your room as well? The ZED documentation also says that using the reference frame setting can cause jumps in VR, when syncing to the reference. Would this be a big problem? Because if it would jump all the time, that would only increase motion sickness, which is a big enough problem as it is in VR. And finally, would it require a lot of processing power to track using a reference frame? Because we're dealing with standalone headsets here powered by mobile processors, they have a hard enough time of it as it is.

Or would it be feasible to make something using markers and maybe Vuforia and do absolute positional tracking that way?

Thanks for any input!